# JQuery AJAX + PHP Login

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication

I am using PHP + jQuery AJAX to log a user into my site. The PHP connects to the database and the jquery connects to the PHP file and everything works until it comes time to actually log in. When I type in my username and password, the file returns an error. I had this working about a week ago but I was doing some code cleanup and I accidentally deleted the script where it performed the log in and now I can't get it to work. Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php 
include('.conf.php');
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accountController WHERE username = '$user'");while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if (sha1($user.$pass) == $row['pword']) {
    setcookie('temp', $row['username']);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $row['username'];
    echo "success";
}
}
?>
```

I do believe the PHP file is echoing the correct statement and yes, the passwords in the database are sha1 encrypted. Here is the jquery code:

```
            $('.mainlogin').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'log.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              user: username,
              pass: password
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response == 'success') {
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('.logerror').fadeIn(250);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Thanks for all the help!

EDIT: I am not sure what is wrong right now but it won't log me in no matter what I try. I have corrected everything you guys suggested below, but to no avail. Anything wrong in my PHP file possibly?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  He had a legitimate error and couldn't find it?  At least explain yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
  $('.mainlogin').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'log.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                  username: username,
                  password:password
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response == 'success') {
                    window.location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('.logerror').fadeIn(250);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

or chaneg data params

> data: 'username='+username+'&password='+password

AND USE **&**!!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still dosn't work. Is there an error in the PHP i should be aware of? Thanks again

Comment: @JosephTorraca, change your `_POST` to `_GET`, hit the page directly with valid parameters in the querystring, and check the PHP error that comes back.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo:

```
data: 'user='+username+'pass='+password,
```

should be:

```
data: 'user='+username+'&pass='+password,
```

or use @Olaf's alternative, which makes sure you don't make mistakes like that.

Answer (score 1):

What others have said.  The '&' is needed to separate your parameters.

On a somewhat related note, you might want to consider salting those passwords...